# php taking array as string

Tags: php, request

I am sending an array from url as

```
x=[2,3,5,1]
```

and receiving as

```
$x=$_REQUEST['x'];
```

and trying to access elements. But for `$x[0]` it prints `[`.

This means it's taking it as string. I searched but did not find a solution.

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted, in order to help future visitors find the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it as a JSON string. Try this:

```
$x = json_decode($_REQUEST['x']);
```

Comment: ok problem solved.but i dont get y it was taking it as string

Comment: You're passing it through a URL which means it parses it as a string when you do a simple request. You need to do it as a JSON like Ahmad posted or you can do what I did.

Comment: PHP can parse an array if you have a form with an input set as a array and post that form.

Comment: This is completely different from what you tried. Design such a form and send it using GET, and you will understand what I say.

Comment: This will help you understand what Ahmad and I are saying.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JSON or don't know how, you could also do a str_replace on the [ and ] with "" and then explode the string using "," as a delimiter.

Example:

index.php?x=[a,b,c,d]

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
$brackets = array("[", "]");
$x = str_replace($brackets, "", $x); // this gives you $x = "a,b,c,d"
$x = explode(",", $x); // this gives you $x = {0=>"a", 1=>"b", 2=>"c", 3=>"d"}
```